# How can I position gps point on svg (or any other special type if exist) scheme of building?

Tags: geojson, gps, svg, navigation, indoor

I have an indoor map of a building in svg and this is an only scheme of a building, there is no google maps or any other maps. But I need positioning (navigation) by gps coordinates in this scheme.

There is no problem to get coordinates value by gps. The question is how to set current position point on the right place in indoor svg scheme?

Some ideas:

1. Get vertex coordinates of polygon (where building is placed) from google maps.
2. Left-bottom vertex is our base coordinates value (eg. lat: 50, lng: 60)
3. For now we have gps coordinates from phone lat: 50,12302 lng: 60,01234 and we can position point relatively base coordinates(step 2)
4. Can't imagine how to tie svg scheme and polygon coordinates.

Also, I think I found solution to use GeoJSON(TopoJSON) and D3.js. But how can you connect full building scheme to GeoJSON borders of building only?

Does anyone know an existing well-tried way or have code examples?